# Obtain a field that is inside 2 superclasses

Tags: java, unit-testing, reflection

I want to obtain a field that is inside a super class of a class that I'm extending, to undesrstand it better:

```
class A
{
   private int a = 3; 
}

class B extends A
{

}

class C extends B
{
 // I want to access a value here
}
```

In C have tried `Field a = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass().getField("a");` with no sucess

while if in B I put `Field a = this.getClass().getSuperclass().getField("a");` I obtain the field.

How it is possible in class C to obtain a?

PD: I am doing this for a unit test